# I need grammatical explanation for this sentence "its poor torn mouth an O of agony"

Tags: grammar

I need grammatical explanation for this sentence "*its poor torn mouth an O of agony*". It's weird to me that there is no verb in this sentence, I think it would be like "*It's poor torn mouth **formed** an O of agony*"

Full context:

> The boy seized it and tore the bait from its mouth, ripping it horribly.
>
> 'Oh!' I whispered, covering my own lips.
>
> It got a lot worse. The fish was flopping about frantically, its poor torn mouth an O of agony.

From "Buried Alive" by Jacqueline Wilson

Answer (score 2):

Actually it doesn't need a verb there, because there is already a main clause with a verb ("was flopping"). You could also write:

> The fish was flopping about frantically, its poor torn mouth [like] an O of agony.

Compare:

> I went to sleep, tired as a log.

> She was screaming, [with] her hair [in] a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Some people refer to such clauses as "absolutes" and others call them "free adjuncts". They act as modifiers of the main clause and can omit a form of the verb-to-be. Semantically they pertain to the main clause but syntactically they're disconnected from it.

> *His hat at a rakish angle*, he strode up to the bar and ordered a whisky, neat.